# Backup из Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, резервное-копирование, android-gradle

Скажите, можно ли создать gradle task (или иное средство) для автоматизация бекапа приложения прямо из Android Studio.
Напр, такие шаги:

- очистить проект;
- с помощью команды 7z.exe упаковать проект в нужное место;
- добавить дату к архивному фалу.

Какие варианты?

Comment: А чем Вас git не устраивает?

Comment: Это не имеет отношения к вопросу .

Answer (score 1):

Ну тогда конечно можно и gradle task и всё что душе угодно. Проект - это такая же папка с файлами, как и любая другая. Поэтому можете делать с ней что хотите любыми удобными для Вас средствами. Если хотите именно грэдлом, вбейте в гугл "gradle task" и минут через 5-10 сможете вывести в консоль свой "привет мир". Для Вашей задачи нужно: зависимость от таска clean, стандартный таск Exec для запуска 7z + ещё немножко кода.
Примитивчик для начала размышлений:

```
task saveMyProjectPlease(dependsOn: clean, type: Exec) {
    commandLine "path/to/7z.exe", "arg1" ..., "argN"
}
```

Comment: Ну начало положено :). Но я не хочу именно гредлом, хотя можно и гредлом.

Comment: Да пишите на чём хотите: java, плюсы, питон... хоть батник пишите - в папку с проектом бросил, запустил дабл-кликом или из терминала и "Алга, комсомол!!!"